# ms-access same data entry for multiple userid's

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have a vacation database that tracks gained and used time.  I have just found a shortfall in my applications design. For national holidays our managers that work receive a deferred holiday.  I have found that my data entry form is tiedious to enter a single event for each userid.  Is is possible to have a form that will input the same basic information for many different userid's?

```
Table: SchedulingLog (uses a composite primary key)
LogID - UserID(pri) - LogDate - EventDate(pri) - Category(pri) - CatDetail(pri) - Value
auto#    abc123       1-1-13    1-1-13           DH              DH Gain           1
auto#    def789       1-1-13    1-1-13           DH              DH Gain           1
auto#    xyz567       1-1-13    1-1-13           DH              DH Gain           1
```

My Current Form has a drop box to select the manager, then all of the corresponding fields for the table SchedulingLOG.  What my ultimate goal is to be able to batch enter the DH event for some 100 different users by some form of checkboc or list box for multi users for the userid, and then key the remaining fields.  Then click an update event that will generate a record for each user with the same information (except userid of course).

Comment: A calendar table is pretty nearly essential for a vacation database.

Comment: I have never used anything like that.  Can you refer me to some training material?

Comment: You will find a lot on google, for example : http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Comment: Thank Remou! If you would like to post taht as the answer I will accept.